# Keyboard shortcuts blocking in MDI

Tags: vb.net

Why is it I can trap the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> etc., keyboard shortcuts in a testbox when in a MDI, but can't trap them when in a child form of a MDI.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the default Edit menu the parent form 'eats' the ctrl shortcuts before they reach the child forms. You can remove the shortcut keys on the edit menu (remove the & from the menu text) and you should be OK